# Deploying WCF on IIS 8.5

Tags: wcf, windows-8.1, web-config, iis-8.5

I am attempting to deploy a IIS service application on IIS 8.5 but each time I attemp to connect to the service via `http://localhost/test/WCFService.svc` I get the following screen:

[image]

When I go to `turn Windows features On or OFF` I have the following:

[image]

My web.config looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name ="MessageServaceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

    </behaviors>
    <services>

      <service name ="WCF_Connection.WCFService" behaviorConfiguration="MessageServaceBehavior">

        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://10.0.5.32:58632/WCF_Service/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint name ="getMessage" address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCF_Connection.IWCFService"/>
         <!--<endpoint name ="MessgaeServiceMex" address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>-->        

      </service>
    </services>

   <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>

       <!-- To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.-->

    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

What causes this and how can i fix this problem?

Comment: Try to install all features down the internet information service and internet information service hostable web core then copy your website to wwwroot folder

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are probably missing WCF HTTP activation feature. It is in different section of Windows Feature screen (look at the screen below) and as far as I know it is not enabled by default when you install IIS.

[image]